# How to say "plural things in many groups"?

Tags: grammar

I want to make sentence fulfilling this condition:

> Three groups consist of different people in each, let's say "A people", "B people, "C people"

Is it,

> "Three people group"

or

> "Three people groups"

I'm confused about **plural things in plural group**. Could anyone explain me with examples?

I think my question's title is confusing but I have no good words to make it. If this question is a duplicate, please let me know!

Comment: So you have three groups each with multiple people?  Does that do it?

Comment: @deadrat Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is

> Three groups of people

*People* is the plural of person, and *groups* is the plural of group. *Of* specifies what the group contains.

Comment: +1. And for the OP: it goes beyond "groups": three piles of money,  five rooms of furniture, two stacks of coins, six pints of beer...